# Object not zeroing out to the center of the grid

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am having an issue where an object is not zeroing out to the center of the grid. it is not parented to anything and its pivot point is where it is pictured in the image...

Appreciate any help!

[image: object at 0,0,0, yet not at center of the grid/world]

With moving object to center and freezing location, the pivot moves up to where it thinks 0,0,0 is...

[image]

Blend file for download:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"zeroing out to the center of the grid"*? Do you want to snap selection to the cursor? Did you try Shift+S > Selection To Cursor in that case?

Comment: Na sorry, it (the object or blender or something) believes 0,0,0 is where the pivot is in the above image

Comment: That's strange.Did you snap selection to cursor in Object mode?

Comment: Yeah I did do that

Comment: Excellent, I've added the blend file to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set delta location in the [*Delta Transform*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html#delta-transforms) rollout which is now adding transforms to the current location.

[image]

Reset it back to 0 for all the options and origin point will be moving to 0 once location applied. This can be done either manually or via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> menu > *Location To Deltas* after you snapped selection to cursor (which should be in the desired location already, center in this case).

[image: gif-of-the-process]

Comment: That Delta Transforms was it!! Thanks so much. I have never used that function either

Answer (score 0):

You have probably just reset the location scale by accident. To move your object to the center of the grid hit Shift +S with the object selected and move it to the grid (selection to cursor). For that your cursor has to be on the grid center b.t.w.. If it’s not hit shift + s and cursor to center. Now hit ctrl + A and then location to set the current location to zero, essentially taring it (like with a weight scale).  Hope that helps!

Addition: At the bottom of the screen, there is a tool bar where next to where you switch views (3D—>Rendered etc) there is a button where you can configure the pivot of the selected object. Set it to active element I think.

Also, if none of that works go to the toolbar and in tools under Set Origin change it to origin to 3D cursor.

Comment: Yeah I've tried doing that eh, if I snap selection to cursor, with the cursor at the center, then freeze transforms, the pivot goes off up to where the object is in the first image...

Comment: I've edited the original post to show an image of this

Comment: Oh yes I see. That quite odd. Let me see if I can find a fix.

Comment: I’m editing my answer as I think I’ve got it!

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but na they don't seem to change it :/

Comment: Anytime. That sucks man. I’ll see if I can find anything else. Did you do anything to the mesh besides edit it and move it? Maybe try duplicating it and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem to change it eh! I've added the blend file to the original post

Comment: Wow. If I can I’ll see if I can do anything. Good luck man. Tell me if you figure it out.

Comment: Raiyan the answer is posted above, it turns out to be the Delta Transforms. Which is my first encounter with such things!

Comment: Me neither! I guess we all learn something new everyday :)